# Passing Strings Using Tags

Tags: android

I'm creating multiple Views in my Custom Adapter Class. I would like each view to be associated with two TextView Objects, each with different Strings as their main Texts. I'm having an issue passing the Strings between my getView and onClick functions. I was able to use a tag to get it to work with one of my objects (gridcell)

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_grid_date, parent, false);
    }

    gridcell = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calendarDayButton);
    gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

    gridcell.setTag(themonth + " " + theday + " " + theyear);
    return row;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String month_day_year = (String) view.getTag();

    selectedDay.setText(month_day_year);//WORKS FIN
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do it with more than one object. Below, I added another TextView object called test. How can I get that TextView to get another String using Tags? I tried using an index int then the String in the setTag parameter but the app keeps crashing:

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_grid_date, parent, false);
    }

    gridcell = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calendarDayButton);
    test = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.test);
    gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

    gridcell.setTag(1, themonth + " " + theday + " " + theyear);
    test.setTag(2,"Test");
    return row;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String month_day_year = (String) view.getTag(1);
    String Test = (String) view.getTag(2)

    selectedDay.setText(Test);
}
```

I'm not familiar with using Tags in general and was wondering how I could pass a String value from one method to the next. Every time I try and set an Integer as a tag, I get the following error in my log cat:

```
10-05 16:02:05.599  14723-14723/com.markfeldman.mycalendar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.markfeldman.mycalendar, PID: 14723
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key must be an application-specific resource id.
        at android.view.View.setTag(View.java:17297)
        at com.markfeldman.mycalendar.GridCellAdapter.getView(GridCellAdapter.java:173)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
        at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1060)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

10-05 16:07:06.043  14723-14723/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 14723 SIG: 9

Comment: just use, `gridcell.setTag(1, themonth + " " + theday + " " + theyear);
   gridcell.setTag(2,"Test");` This will work on your onClick with only one `TextView gridcell`.

Comment: It won't allow me to user 1 or 2, etc. My log cat keeps giving me this error: The key must be an application-specific resource id.

Comment: Is there any limitation of calling onClick on one TextView?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, I pasted the entire log cat error above

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_grid_date, parent, false);
    }

    gridcell = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calendarDayButton);
    test = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.test);
    gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);
    // add click listener for test too
    test.setOnClickListener(this);

    gridcell.setTag(1, themonth + " " + theday + " " + theyear);
    test.setTag(2,"Test");
    return row;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  switch(view.getId()){
   case R.id. calendarDayButton:
     String month_day_year = (String) view.getTag(1);
     break;
   case R.id. test:
     String Test = (String) view.getTag(2);
     selectedDay.setText(Test);
     break;
  }
}
```